# CakePHP 3 Custom Logging

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am trying to configure a custom log-file but I do not understand the official documentation's examples.

It describes how to use the FileLog Adapter by specifying a stanza like the following and put it into the config/app.php file (however the app.php file is not consistent with this format):

```
Log::config('custom_path', [
'className' => 'File',
'path' => '/path/to/custom/place/'
]);
```

And then, presumably, to use this stanza in a class file as follows:

```
$this->log("Something didn't work!", 'custom_path');
```

But then a message is written to the custom_path file containing the error

```
Invalid log level "custom_path"
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to add scopes in your log configuration.. copy paste this :

```
Log::config('custom_path', [
'className' => 'File',
'path' => '/path/to/custom/place/'
'scopes' => ['custom_path']
]);
```